# Hacking the Open JDK - Emit LLVM Assembler rather than Java Bytecode

Tags: compiler-construction, javac, bytecode, java

I have got the opportunity to work at the university and to help hacking `javac` from the OpenJDK. The goal is to read custom sourcecode (for "our" programming language in combination with antlr) and not to write out Java bytecode - the compiler should write out LLVM assembler code. This would be my task, however the project is so huge that i don't know where or how to start understanding what's going on there. I was told to try out debugging the code and going through it step-by-step but i would like to know whether there is any good documentation out in the wild given me a short breakthrough to understand which parts are the most important ones.

Comment: [1] Sounds like a cool project
[2] Sounds like a too much big project in real life (dealing with 2 compiler frameworks: Java, LLVM)
[3] Are you sure you want to deal with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "myprogram.myprogrlang" into "myprogram.llvm".

I don't see the need to use / hack javac. I think you want to use the compiler tools of Java / openjdk, but I think that only makes your task more difficult, instead of helping you.

My suggestion is take antlr, learn how does it work to parse a program in your programming language, how to generate an AST, and then turn that AST data into the LLVM bytecode or assembler.

You don't need java in this case.

So:

[1] Learn ANTLR grammars /rules for your programming language

[2] Learn LLVM bytecode / assembler

[3] Learn how to turn ANTLR data output into LLVM data input

Comment: Java was used because the language's syntax is influenced by Java and we are still at the beginning where AST are created and punched through the java compiler to output the Java equivalent of the language. Through my search i found [Kaleidoscope](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html) which seems to be that what i need - however, my supervisor told me that they've already tried writing such a wrapper for Java/C++ calling the LLVM API which failed, in the end. The first step for me is to understand how code is created and to try emitting basic "things" in LLVM ASM.(like binops)

Comment: Furthermore, the reason of choosing LLVM Assembler is just for optimization - which happens automatically during compilation, so i do not need to write code that is 100% optimized :-)

Comment: @Christian Ivicevic. I haven't work with ANTLR or LLVM, lack of time. My previous answer was more generic, and compiler based. But, seems you are in good track. As intermediate step, you could learn how to make a TEXT program in LLVM ASM, and later, make a compiler from your lang. into a TEXT LLVM ASM.